# Spring MVC can't run on linux(CentOS)

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-mvc

I use eclipse to develop.
My spring project can run on Mac, but can't run on CentOS.
I can't find out why.
It seems like it can't create bean on CentOS.
Please give me some directions.

Here is some console:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate ... throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception;
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ...
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mappingMongoConverter() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ' ' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/servlet-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class

Comment: Because you are missing to instantiate bean in xml. Check your bean reference in servlet-config.xml.

Comment: Looks like you are using different dependencies on your mac and the server. Check the class path.